# not all code path return value?

Tags: c#, json, async-await

I am struggeling with this part of my code. Could you guys help me out ?

```
static public async Task<Artikelen> getItems (string f = "")
    {
        await EnsureAccess();
        string filter = "&$filter=substringof('" + f + "',Code)+eq+true";
        string orderby = "&$orderby=Code+asc";
        Uri request = new Uri(Gegevens.BASE_URI + "/api/v1/" + CurrentDivision + "/logistics/Items?access_token=" + AccessToken + filter + orderby);

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        //  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/multipart/form-data"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
        HttpResponseMessage respons = await client.GetAsync(request);
        if (respons.IsSuccessStatusCode == false)
        {
            //await errorAlert("getSalesItemPrices Mislukt:  status = " + respons.StatusCode.ToString());
            return null;
        }
        respons.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string responsecontent = await respons.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        //JArray results = JObject.Parse(responsecontent).GetValue("d")["results"].First.ToObject<JArray>();
        JArray results = JObject.Parse(responsecontent).GetValue("d")["results"].ToObject<JArray>();
    }
```

the error is in the JArray results

```
JObject.Parse(responsecontent).GetValue("d")["results"].ToObject<JArray>();
```

I think is should return a value or something?

Comment: Your method should return a task, while you don´t return anything when everything worked correct, I guess you need `return result`, don´t you?

Comment: You need create instance of `Artikelen` and return it in case `respons.IsSuccessStatusCode == true`

Comment: FYI the error message tells you all you need to know, not all your code paths return a value.